# New Spin on cURL not working over SSL

Tags: php, curl

So I've been finding a lot of posts here and other places on the interwebs regarding PHP, cURL and SSL.  I've got a problem that I'm not seeing around.

Obviously, if I set SSL_VERIFYPEER/HOST to blindly accept I can get this to work, but I would like to use my cert to verify the connection.

So here is some code:

```
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $oAuthResult['signed_url'],
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
            CURLOPT_CAINFO => getcwd() . '\application\third_party\certs\rootCerr.crt'

        );
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    try {
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $errCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200) {
            throw new Exception('<strong>Error trying to ExecuteWebRequest, returned: '.$errCode .'<br>URL:'.$url . '<br>POST data (if any):</strong><br>');
        }   

        curl_close($ch);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //print the error stuff
    }
```

The error code that is returned is 0...which means that everything is A-OK...but since nothing comes back to the screen...I'm pretty sure it's not working.

Anyone?

Comment: Turns out it was a domain issue.  I'm not 100% sure about this, but the way it was explained to me was that since the site was on a subdomain, we needed to have a wildcard cert.  Once we got that, everything worked.  I might be explaining that totally wrong and if I am I'll update later, but once we got the right SSL stuff setup this code worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The $errCode you extract is the HTTP code which is 200-299 when OK. Getting 0 means it was never set due to a problem or similar.

You should rather use curl_errno() after curl_exec() to figure out if things went fine or not. (You can't check the curl_exec() return code for errors as easily, as you have CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER enabled which makes that function instead return the contents of the transfer it is set to get. Of course, getting no contents at all returned should also be a good indicator that something failed.)

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented LibCurl Certs by using the CURLOPT_CAINFO as you have indicated...

However, by providing the file name itself wasn't good enough... It had crashed on me too.

For me, the file was referenced by relative path... Additionally, I had to make sure the cert was in Base64 format too. Then everything went through without a hitch..